# What have been so far the benefits of the competition between construction sites for Starship by SpaceX?

Tags: spacex-starship, construction

As [stated by Elon Musk himself](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1128448802942177280), the construction of the prototypes of the future space vehicle by SpaceX, Starship, should benefit from the competition between two teams at Boca Chica and the Cape Canaveral.

With [the apparent closure of the Cape Cocoa site](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-starship-hardware-mystery-solved/), can we know whether there have been any benefits from this unusual internal competition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superficially a few lessons appear to have been learned.

The windbreak first built in the FL site appears to have been replicated in TX in slightly different form.

Several of the structures built (stands to mount rings on, for fixed work) were moved from FL to the TX site.

The use of coils of stainless, to form rings instead of pre-curved thicker section appears to have started in FL and moved to be used in TX.

Comment: benefits, nice, but not worth the duplicate effort, since they closed the second site?

Comment: @theworldisnotflat Aye, and thus the shutdown. They tried it till it was clear it was not needed, and they moved on to Plan C, then Plan D, and so on.

Comment: "The windbreak first built in the FL site appears to have been replicated in TX in slightly different form." how do you know this? How do we know you're not just making this up? If you can at least mention where this can be verified, that would be great! Temporary, reversible `-1` If you ping me when edited I'' reverse it. Thanks!